# I am trying to flip/mirror an hdmi signal and would like to use a Pi to do it

Tags: hdmi

I need to get an hdmi signal to show a mirror image(not duplicate) that i would like to put inline of a video feed. So it would be: SOURCE—>outputCABLE-->PI—->CABLE—>TO MONITOR. Is it a possible use or do i need to look into other options?

Comment: first, you'd need some sort of video "capture" device on the pi

Comment: it may be easier to find a monitor that does horizontal flip

Comment: I have gone as far as reaching out to monitor manufacturers for this, do you have any recommendations for a monitor that would do that?